# How do I make alternating lines in a graphic visually distinct?

Tags: color, color-theory

I draw a graphic consisting of N lines. I want every two lines to have a different color in order to be visually distinct.

Question: Which colors would you recommend? The longer the list, the better, because I need only first N colors, where N varies.

Answer (score 1):

If "visually distinct" is the goal, then vary the contrast as much as possible. [Complementary colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_colors) help, as does contrasting light/dark and/or saturation. Combining those (using Goethe's color wheel) gives you something like this:

[image: Visually distinct lines]

Answer (score 0):

**The HSB sliders are an easy way to control this.** Brightness and Hue will give you the most visually apparent results. Saturation is for fine tuning.

Obviously, big shifts will give you more distinctness. On the other hand, something like a green and blue (close on the Hue slider) of the same Saturation and Brightness will give you subtle variation.

This combo will be more distinct

[image]  -VS-  [image]

This combo will be more subtle

[image]  -VS-  [image]